# What is the best practice to manage EC2 instance up/down/hibernate scheduler?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have 2 - 3 EC2 c5.9xlarge instances for research.
Besides the option to shut them down on a particular hour according to a scheduler please advise what is the best way to keep them up and running when I "touch" them by connecting/clicking them or any other wake up policy?

My goal is to save expenses and I am trying to find a best practice to manage these instances wisely.

Please advise from your professional experience.

Comment: I know that hibernating can be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the EC2 Hibernation feature via which you can pause/resume your instances. This would give you the convenience of resuming your instances with all the processes running just like the way you had left the instance saving you a lot of time and effort in setting up the environment and reach your productive state faster.

Currently, EC2 Hibernation is available for Amazon Linux 2, Amazon Linux and Ubuntu 18.04. It is supported for your instance type which you use.

More details can be viewed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have Jenkins or other CI/CD tool available you can create a job there that would enable/disable particular EC2 instances. If you want something smaller then you can use aws-cli with cron and do the same. Some of my customers turn their VMs on at 7 AM and turn them off at 7 PM (mostly for testing/staging environments).